# Is it possible to login through SAML uisng rest API

Tags: java, rest, single-sign-on, saml, idp

I am trying to ,ogin to a saml enabled application using rest api instead of browser. I am getting 401 error. Is it possible to login using REST. Any extra steps i need to take care of.

Answer (score 1):

SAML is basically a set of tokens. Most SAML access is done via the browser using a browser based SAML profile such as Web Browser Single Sign On (WBSSO). Have a look at the Enhanced Client or Proxy SAML profile (ECP) but the SP needs to support it:

[ECP SAML Profile](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/ECP)