# How to programatically log in with SAML2 against Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, wildfly, keycloak

We have a Java application running on Wildfly. We use the [Redhat keycloak adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/14.0/securing_apps/index.html#_jboss_adapter) to authenticate against Microsoft Azure via SAML2.

This works fine for users. For example, If a user opens the application

1. The keycloak saml2 adapter redirects the user to the Microsoft login page (https://login.microsoftonline.com/...) with the SAMLRequest.
2. The user can login with userid/password
3. And the user is redirected back to the wildfly app. The user is now authenticated in wildfly and a JSESSIONID is used for further requests as usual.

But how can I login programmatically? I have for example backend services which need to request data form the app. I already tried to implement a java RequestFilter but this works only until the point I get redirected to the Microsoft Login Page for users. This login page consists only of JavaScript (!) and I can not post my UserID/Password to get redirected back.

Does somebody knows how to do a Azure AD Login in java or with curl? Or is there any alternative URL for the Login not based on Javascript - maybe some Rest API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to login through SAML uisng rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648706/is-it-possible-to-login-through-saml-uisng-rest-api)

Comment: No. The Microsoft login url (https://login.microsoftonline.com/...) provides only a heavy java script page. To login programmatically, I think a more api based endpoint is needed where I can post my userid/password to receive the SAML Response. The question is: does Microsoft supports such an api? And how does it work?

Comment: Yes, that is an anwser. SAML is (old) browser/XML based SSO protocol, not API. OIDC was designed also for APIs/JSON. There is SAML ECP for API. There is many question "I want SAML login via API", but no real API answer (I don't count that hackish approaches, which simulates browser) . Why? Because it is browser based.